# laravel 4.2 liebig package work on localhost but fail in server cron job command

Tags: php, linux, laravel, cron

i want to fire some function to get news about football from rss 
i used laravel4.2 [https://github.com/liebig/cron](http://liebig%20package)
as that

```
Event::listen('cron.collectJobs', function() {
Cron::add('football', '* * * * *', function() {
      //the controller of function
                $news=new News_feedController();
                $news->football();
                return 'success';
            });
         });
 $report = Cron::run();
```

it work correctly when i use cmd

> php artisan cron:run

in my computer
but when use the server cron job command

> - - - - - /usr/bin/php /home/public_html/interestoo.com/artisan cron:run

i don't find any change in

> cron_job

table but find data in

> cron_manager

table 
and the cron job function did not work 
i'm sure that the path

> /home/sfathy/public_html/interestoo.com/

in command is true and does not find any reason for that problem
 any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to give this a try `usr/bin/php5 /home/public_html/interestoo.com/artisan cron:run` due to laravel required php>=5.4